# How do I determine the coefficients for a linear regression line in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, numerical-methods

I'm going to write a program where the input is a data set of 2D points and the output is the regression coefficients of the line of best fit by minimizing the minimum MSE error.

I have some sample points that I would like to process:

```
  X      Y
1.00    1.00
2.00    2.00
3.00    1.30
4.00    3.75
5.00    2.25
```

How would I do this in MATLAB?

Specifically, I need to get the following formula:

```
y = A + Bx + e
```

`A` is the intercept and `B` is the slope while `e` is the residual error per point.

Comment: Congrats! where is the question?

Comment: Check [`polyfit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html)

Comment: If you have sample data that you want to use to fit, then we'd be more inclined to help you.

Comment: please see this link [link](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/intro.html)

Comment: thank you.i comfused about QR,please expalin about Q and R in your formula that you wrote under

Comment: ok tank you.i got it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Judging from the link you provided, and my understanding of your problem, you want to calculate the line of best fit for a set of data points.  You also want to do this from first principles.  This will require some basic Calculus as well as some linear algebra for solving a 2 x 2 system of equations.  If you recall from linear regression theory, we wish to find the best slope `m` and intercept `b` such that for a set of points `([x_1,y_1], [x_2,y_2], ..., [x_n,y_n])` (that is, we have `n` data points), we want to minimize the sum of squared residuals between this line and the data points.

In other words, we wish to minimize the cost function `F(m,b,x,y)`:

[image]

`m` and `b` are our slope and intercept for this best fit line, while `x` and `y` are a vector of **`x`** and **`y`** co-ordinates that form our data set.

This function is convex, so there is an optimal minimum that we can determine.  The minimum can be determined by finding the derivative with respect to each parameter, and setting these equal to 0.  We then solve for `m` and `b`.  The intuition behind this is that we are simultaneously finding `m` and `b` such that the cost function is jointly minimized by these two parameters.  In other words:

[image]

OK, so let's find the first quantity [image]:

[image]

We can drop the factor 2 from the derivative as the other side of the equation is equal to 0, and we can also do some distribution of terms by multiplying the `-x_i` term throughout:

[image]

Next, let's tackle the next parameter [image]:

[image]

We can again drop the factor of 2 and distribute the -1 throughout the expression:

[image]

Knowing that [image] is simply `n`, we can simplify the above to:

[image]

Now, we need to simultaneously solve for `m` and `b` with the above two equations.  This will jointly minimize the cost function which finds the best line of fit for our data points.

Doing some re-arranging, we can isolate `m` and `b` on one side of the equations and the rest on the other sides:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, we can formulate this into a 2 x 2 system of equations to solve for `m` and `b`.  Specifically, let's re-arrange the two equations above so that it's in matrix form:

[image]

[image]

---

With regards to above, we can decompose the problem by solving a linear system: `Ax = b`.  All you have to do is solve for `x`, which is `x = A^{-1}*b`.  To find the inverse of a 2 x 2 system, given the matrix:

[image]

The inverse is simply:

[image]

Therefore, by substituting our quantities into the above equation, we solve for `m` and `b` in matrix form, and it simplifies to this:

[image]

Carrying out this multiplication and solving for `m` and `b` individually, this gives:

[image]

### [image]

As such, to find the best slope and intercept to best fit your data, you need to calculate `m` and `b` using the above equations.

Given your data specified in the link in your comments, we can do this quite easily:

```
%// Define points
X = 1:5;
Y = [1 2 1.3 3.75 2.25];

%// Get total number of points
n = numel(X);

% // Define relevant quantities for finding quantities
sumxi = sum(X);
sumyi = sum(Y);
sumxiyi = sum(X.*Y);
sumxi2 = sum(X.^2);
sumyi2 = sum(Y.^2);

%// Determine slope and intercept
m = (sumxi * sumyi - n*sumxiyi) / (sumxi^2 - n*sumxi2);
b = (sumxiyi * sumxi - sumyi * sumxi2) / (sumxi^2 - n*sumxi2);

%// Display them
disp([m b])
```

... and we get:

```
0.4250  0.7850
```

Therefore, the line of best fit that minimizes the error is:

```
y = 0.4250*x + 0.7850
```

---

However, if you want to use built-in MATLAB tools, you can use [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) (credit goes to Luis Mendo for providing the hint).  `polyfit` determines the line (or n<sup>th</sup> order polynomial curve rather...) of best fit by linear regression by minimizing the sum of squared errors between the best fit line and your data points.  How you call the function is so:

```
coeff = polyfit(x,y,order);
```

`x` and `y` are the `x` and `y` points of your data while `order` determines the order of the line of best fit you want.  As an example, `order=1` means that the line is linear, `order=2` means that the line is quadratic and so on.  Essentially, `polyfit` fits a polynomial of order `order` given your data points.  Given your problem, `order=1`.  As such, given the data in the link, you would simply do:

```
X = 1:5;
Y = [1 2 1.3 3.75 2.25];
coeff = polyfit(X,Y,1)

coeff =

    0.4250    0.7850
```

The way `coeff` works is that these are the coefficients of the regression line, starting from the highest order in decreasing value.  As such, the above `coeff` variable means that the regression line was fitted as:

```
y = 0.4250*x + 0.7850
```

The first coefficient is the slope while the second coefficient is the intercept.  You'll also see that this matches up with the link you provided.

If you want a visual representation, here's a plot of the data points as well as the regression line that best fits these points:

```
plot(X, Y, 'r.', X, polyval(coeff, X));
```

Here's the plot:

[image]

[`polyval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) takes an array of coefficients (usually produced by `polyfit`), and you provide a set of `x` co-ordinates and it calculates what the `y` values are given the values of `x`.  Essentially, you are evaluating what the points are along the best fit line.

---

## Edit - Extending to higher orders

If you want to extend so that you're finding the best fit for any n<sup>th</sup> order polynomial, I won't go into the details, but it boils down to constructing the following linear system.  Given the relationship for the i<sup>th</sup> point between `(x_i, y_i)`:

[image]

You would construct the following linear system:

[image]

Basically, you would create a vector of points `y`, and you would construct a matrix `X` such that each column denotes taking your vector of points `x` and applying a power operation to each column.  Specifically, the first column is the zero-th power, the first column is the first power, the second column is the second power and so on.  You would do this up until `m`, which is the order polynomial you want.  The vector of `e` would be the residual error for each point in your set.

Specifically, the formulation of the problem can be written in matrix form as:

[image]

Once you construct this matrix, you would find the parameters by least-squares by calculating the [pseudo-inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).  How the pseudo-inverse is derived, you can read it up on the Wikipedia article I linked to, but this is the basis for minimizing a system by least-squares.  The pseudo-inverse is the backbone behind least-squares minimization.  Specifically:

[image]

`(X^{T}*X)^{-1}*X^{T}` is the pseudo-inverse.  `X` itself is a very popular matrix, which is known as the [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and MATLAB has a command called [`vander`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vander.html) to help you compute that matrix.  A small note is that `vander` in MATLAB is returned in reverse order.  The powers decrease from `m-1` down to 0.  If you want to have this reversed, you'd need to call [`fliplr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) on that output matrix.  Also, you will need to append one more column at the end of it, which is the vector with all of its elements raised to the m<sup>th</sup> power.

I won't go into how you'd repeat your example for anything higher order than linear.  I'm going to leave that to you as a learning exercise, but simply construct the vector `y`, the matrix `X` with `vander`, then find the parameters by applying the pseudo-inverse of `X` with the above to solve for your parameters.

---

Good luck!

Comment: thank you a lot. but my problem is that i want write my code instead od use polyfit,and i need polyfit algoritm

Comment: @abbasmahmudi - That's easy.  I can update my post if you like.

Comment: @rayryeng-thank you. please update your post,tahk you again

Comment: @abbasmahmudi - I've updated my post.  Be prepared that the understanding of how the slope and intercept are derived requires basic Calculus and linear algebra.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng- woow.its exactly correct and thank you a lot.excusme for more question.this code can extend to more than 2 Polynomial?

Comment: Yes, that will require constructing a matrix of coefficients and finding the pseudo-inverse. I'll update my post.

Comment: @abbasmahmudi - Done. Good luck!

Comment: thank you, i try write extend part,but its dificult for me,thank you for help me an your code above

Comment: @abbasmahmudi - I can't do **all** of the work :)  I spent probably an hour writing up those equations in LaTeX!  It's really not bad at all.  You can solve it in a few lines of code.  If you still can't, then leave me a message here and I **may** (keyword is **may**) be inclined to do it for you.

Comment: I'm really sorry and I thank you very much for the time. Please could you just lets the program code

Comment: @abbasmahmudi maybe later!

Comment: i wrote a few code above .please see this