# Linear regression - find the m value

Tags: matlab

I have two (linear) graphs and I made a linear regression for them by just saying:  `figure(3);plotregression(a,b);`

It works perfectly but I want to find the slope of that regression line. I know the slope (or m-value) mentioned on the y axis of my plot but it's not very precise. Instead of 0.98 it says 1.

Is there a code I can write to get a more precise value for the m / the slope of the regression ? It's already plotted and everything.

Comment: This has already been answered in the past.  See my post that I linked as a duplicate.

Comment: Anyone with a MATLAB Gold Badge: Please close this post to the duplicate I have linked above.  It is exactly what the OP is looking for.  I've tried closing the post and it didn't immediately close it for some reason.

Comment: @rayryeng I have voted too. Gold badge doesn't work for me here either

Comment: @rayryeng I see the Matlab tag was added by Paul R. It wasn't in the original version of the question. That must be the reason

Comment: @LuisMendo - Thanks :) I +1ed you on your answer anyway!

Comment: @PaulR - Thanks for adding the MATLAB tag, and thanks for the add on LinkedIn!

Comment: @rayryeng: you're welcome x2!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`polyfit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) to fit a polynomial of degree 1 in a least-squares sense (that's linear regression):

```
p = polyfit(a, b, 1);
```

`p(1)` is the slope (coefficient of order 1), and `p(2)` is the vertical axis intercept (coefficient of order 0).

Comment: Thanks ! if i just copy paste the p = polyfit(a, b, 1); nothing happens.

Comment: What happens is that you get the variable `p`. `p(2)` is the slope. `polyfit` does not plot anything, it just tells you the slope and y-axis intercept

Comment: @KilianDahlem - Please go to my post that I linked as a duplicate.  It has everything you could want when dealing with regression: (1) Doing it by first principles (2) using `polyfit` and (3) plotting the line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092203/how-do-i-determine-the-coefficients-for-a-linear-regression-line-in-matlab