# Matlab ridge regression with ridge parameter equal to zero gives different results from linear regression

Tags: matlab, regression

I estimate some parameters using both linear regression and ridge regression on matlab. The problem is that when I set the ridge parameter equal to zero, I get different results from the linear regression.
With linear regression:

```
 X = [ones(size(train_matrix,1),1) train_matrix];
 coef = (X\train_ratings)
```

With ridge regression:

```
 coef = ridge(train_ratings,train_matrix,0);
```

I can't find what is wrong..

Thanks in advance

Comment: The size of `train_matrix` and `train_ratings` matters.  What are the sizes of each?  The first formulation assumes that you have a set of **2D** points on a Cartesian plane.  It looks like `train_matrix` is **multi-dimensional**, and that's why you're not getting the right or the same results when comparing between them.

Comment: the size of train_matrix is 930x600 and the size of train_ratings is 930x1. I am not sure that i understand what happens..

Comment: Your first code will definitely not work.  That is trying to find a 2D line that best fits all of the points.  Because `train_matrix` is **multi-dimensional**, you absolutely cannot use the first piece of code.  You have no choice but to use ridge regression on your problem.  See my post on how linear regression coefficients for a simple 2D line is created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092203/how-do-i-determine-the-coefficients-for-a-linear-regression-line-in-matlab/27093747#27093747 .  You will see that it comes down to your first piece of code, but that's assuming your points are 2D.

Comment: i have used this code many times and it works.. i use it for the estimation of 600 weights (for my features on the train_matrix) and i have checked that I take the same results with matlab's function regress(). But I can't understand why if the ridge parameter k is 0 results are different. (Ridge regression with least squares estimation with a penalty defined by k, and thus when k=0 ridge is equal to lse, isn't it?)

Comment: What happens if you use 'fitlm' http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/linear-regression-model-workflow.html?

Comment: i can't use fitlm in the matlab version that i have..

Comment: The matlab 2015a documentation for `ridge()` says "By default, b is computed after centering and scaling the predictors to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1. The model does not include a constant term, and X should not contain a column of 1s.". That could explain the difference.